# add forward slash in bash to a variable string output

Tags: bash

I am pulling my hair on this one for days.. very annoying..

I know it is something to do with utf-8 and string not outputting the proper format, but cant figure out what..

This is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
#test
REGURL=http://bugs.ws
CHECKURL=$(curl -m 3 -sk --head "$REGURL" | grep -i "location" | awk '{print $2}')

if [[ "${CHECKURL: -1}" != *'/'* ]] # if redirected url does not contain / at end, we need to add it
then
    CHECKURL+='/'
    echo "$CHECKURL"
fi
```

This is doing some character substitution rather than simply adding the '/' after the URL..
it works when you do it without a piped curl, grep, so i know it is something dealing with grep or curl..

Basically the outcome MUST have a forward slash at the end, ex: http://bugs.ws will end up having a location redirect of https://alphaterminte.com but I need to add a '/' to the end of "alphatermite.com", I've tried it all, I just cant get the forward slash to go after the variable result.. it keeps substituting it for the first character of the grepped result.. UGHHHH (yes this test code needs to be in bash)

Comment: `[[ "${CHECKURL: -1}" != '/' ]]` would be sufficient. With `curl` there can be oddities due to `curl` returning output with DOS line endings, e.g. `"\r\n"` and many Unix utilities do not play well will them. And you may be very correct that if `CHECKURL` contains and Unicode characters -- all bets are off. UTF-8 can be problematic as well, but is not nearly as problematic as Unicode. (especially if there is a Glyph character embedded in the URL.) Here `"Location: https://alphatermite.comtf-8"` is returned by `curl` which appears the `'\r'` is causing two lines to overlap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output from `curl` is uses carriage return + linefeed line terminators; unix tools only expect linefeed, and treat the carriage return as part of the line's content. Net result: `CHECKURL` has a not-normally-visible carriage return character at the end, which confuses everything.

Specifically, `CHECKURL` winds up containing "`https://alphatermite.com<carriage return>/`", which prints something like:

```
https://alphatermite.com
/
```

...except with only a carriage return (no linefeed) between, the "/" prints over top of the "h" in "https".

Solution: you could add `| tr -d '\r'` to the pipeline creating `CHECKURL`, but I'd just have `awk` do everything in one step:

```
CHECKURL=$(curl -m 3 -sk --head "$REGURL" | awk '/^[Ll]ocation:/ {sub("\r", "", $2); print $2}')
```

Explanation: the `/^[Ll]ocation:/"` part makes it only print the Location (or "location") header, and `sub("\r", "", $2)` deletes the carriage return from `$2` before it's printed.

BTW, I'd use this to test for "/" at the end of the string:

```
if [[ "${CHECKURL}" != *'/' ]]
```

You can either extract the last character and see if it's "/", or use a wildcard pattern to check if it ends with "/"; no need to do both.

BTW2, I also recommend using lower- or mixed-case variable names, to avoid accidentally using one of the many all-caps names that have special meanings (and hence unexpected consequences).

Comment: You my friend are the man. That was exactly the issue, the replacement of "\r" fixes it!!!

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: yes thank you for reminding me, i thought because i didnt have enough reputation score i wasnt going to be able to click the button.

Comment: "BTW2, I also recommend using lower- or mixed-case variable names, to avoid accidentally using one of the many all-caps names that have special meanings (and hence unexpected consequences)." Hmm.. I thought from reading all of the bash tutorials I have, that they recommend using caps so as to not get it mixed up with regular functions or just to know they are variables, maybe adding a "_" in front such as _CHECKURL=$(etc) ?

Comment: @Gordon Davisson: How were you able to quickly see the carriage return from that curl command + grep? I am just asking for future reference, is there a program that outputs all in a certain format that shows everything? Thanks.

Comment: @ealmonte32 There are a variety of opinions about variable capitalization and how to avoid conflicts; I prefer to go with the [POSIX standard on environment variable naming](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html), which says "The name space of environment variable names containing lowercase letters is reserved for applications [i.e. scripts -GD]. Applications can define any environment variables with names from this name space without modifying the behavior of the standard utilities."

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Nope that way to remove whitespace is not working, I just tried it..also, i cannot use capital "L" for location since some headers are using lowercase "location" and some use uppercase... i know not consistent but i dont control it.

emyllalmonte@eambp:~$ CHECKURL=$(curl -m 3 -sk --head "$REGURL" | grep -i "location" | awk '/^Location/{print $2}')
emyllalmonte@eambp:~$ echo "$CHECKURL"
https://alphatermite.com
emyllalmonte@eambp:~$ echo "$CHECKURL"/
/ttps://alphatermite.com
emyllalmonte@eambp:~$

Comment: My bad. Good catch. `CHECKURL=$(curl -m 3 -sk --head "$REGURL" | awk '/^Location/{sub("\r","",$2); print match($2,/\/$/) ? $2 : $2"/"}')` would work for the test as well.

Comment: @ealmonte32 `declare -p CHECKURL | LC_ALL=C cat -vt` will do a good job of making invisible and/or weird unicode characters visible, though it can be hard to figure out exactly what they are. `declare -p CHECKURL | xxd` shows it in hex, which is good for detailed examination.

Comment: @ealmonte32 In `awk`, you can use `/^[Ll]ocation:/` to match a location header with either capitalization of "L". I updated by answer.

Comment: Thank you both @DavidC.Rankin and Gordon Davisson, my final code works like a charm: https://github.com/ealmonte32/csit432/blob/master/checkVT-bash-based.sh

Answer (score 0):

Try bash regex

```
url=http://bugs.ws
re='.*/$'
[[ $url =~ $re ]] || url+='/'
```